I can't use com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2 in kotlin?
<com.hanks.passcodeview.PasscodeView
    android:id="@+id/passcodeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#222222"
    app:firstInputTip="Enter a passcode of 5 digits "
    app:correctStateColor="#71bb4d"
    app:wrongStateColor="#ea2b46"
    app:normalStateColor="#ffffff"
    app:numberTextColor="#222222"
    app:passcodeLength="5"
    app:passcodeViewType="set_passcode"/>

I tried to connect libraries like so but nothing helps in build.gradle
implementation("com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2")
implementation("androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0")


I don't see the library being maintained anymore. Could you try another alternative?

Try to change implementation to compile

dependencies {
implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
compile("com.hanks:passcodeview:0.1.2")
} error!

@АртемУрманов The library is old, you can easily create your own pass code or use another library. Using a library that has not been updated for many years is not very recommended

The library is on the JCenter repository, have you added it to your Gradle?
